# Почему программа работает некорректно?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool a, b, x, o;
    string choose;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (x == true)
        {
            button1.Text = "X";

        }

        if (o == true)
        {
            button1.Text = "O";

        }

        if (button1.Text == "O") x = true;
        if (button1.Text == "X") o = true;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (x == true)
        {
            button2.Text = "X";

        }

        if (o == true)
        {
            button2.Text = "O";

        }

        if (button2.Text == "O") x = true;
        if (button2.Text == "X") o = true;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (x == true)
        {
            if (x == true)
            {
                button3.Text = "X";

            }

            if (o == true)
            {
                button3.Text = "O";

            }

            if (button3.Text == "O") x = true;
            if (button3.Text == "X") o = true;
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (x == true)
        {
            button4.Text = "X";

        }

        if (o == true)
        {
            button4.Text = "O";

        }

        if (button4.Text == "O") x = true;
        if (button4.Text == "X") o = true;
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = true;
    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        o = true;
    } 
}
}
```

**(!)**Заранее извиняюсь за такой громоздкий код, но он нужен, чтобы понять суть программы, и я не прошу чтобы за меня делали работу. **(!)**

Я пытался создать игру "Икс - Нолики". Хотел сделать так: сперва игрок выбирает, кто первым начинает (Х-О). Затем после выбора кликает на один из 9 кнопок и эта кнопка становится выбранным символом (Х - О). Затем, при последующих кликах, прога сама автоматически заменяет Х на О и наоборот. Однако вот именно при этих заменах она не работает и меняет все на либо Х, либо О. Вроде, по логике все правильно должно работать. В чем проблема? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы правильно работало, Вы должны переводить флаги `x` и `o` не только в `true`, но иногда и `false`.

Например:

```
if (button1.Text == "O") {
    x = true;
    o = false;
    // o = !(x = true);
}
if (button1.Text == "X") {
    o = true;
    x = false;
    // o = !(x = false);
}
```

и также в остальных случаях

Comment: сработало! **НО** кликнул - Х, кликнул - О, кликнул - **НИЧЕГО** Почему???

Comment: @navi1893, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению заданий

к томужже в `button3_Click` лишняя проверка

Comment: исправил! Сейчас вот присвоил к label:  
     if (button1.Text == "X" && button5.Text == "X" && button9.Text == "X")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("X WINS!");
            }
Но он не выводит MessageBox! Почему @Spectre?

Comment: без понятия, дебажьте=)